# How to kill a byobu session?

Tags: command-line, session, byobu

byobu allows users to create multiple sessions. Once there are multiple sessions, how to kill an entire session?

If there is a session `foo` with 3 windows and `bar` with 4 windows, to kill session `foo`, user have to run `CTRL+F6` three times in each window to kill an entire session. Is there a better alternative for it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can list byobu current sessions with:

`byobu list-session`

You should see something like this:

`session_1: 1 windows (created Tue Feb  6 18:05:35 2018) [237x49]
session_2: 1 windows (created Tue Feb  6 18:05:44 2018) [237x49]
session_3: 1 windows (created Tue Feb  6 18:06:05 2018) [237x49]`

The first word in every line is the session name.

So, to kill a single session you can do:

`byobu kill-session -t <session_name>`

To kill `session_2` in previous list, you can do:

`byobu kill-session -t session_2`

Answer (score 3):

`ps -u foo`

then

`kill <number1> <number2> ...`

or little care with

`pkill -KILL <pattern>`

This one is not safe when the pattern-name is too short and applied unrelated processes.

`man killall`

Might help understanding.

Answer (score 1):

If your byobu uses GNU screen as backend, use Ctrl+a Ctrl+k to kill current window. See GNU screen manual for more info:https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html